# Is there a way to keep using English as system language on windows 8.1, but have it removed from the language bar?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-layout, language

I'm looking for an alternative to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/755640/is-there-a-way-to-use-three-keyboard-languages-having-two-of-them-being-switcha), but the Internet is full of "How to remove language bar" or "How to remove extra 'US'/languages from language bar".

And nothing on how to keep the default/display language in windows 8.1 to English and have 2 other keyboard layouts to switch between. (Japanese and Bulgarian)

It's possible to write in English with the Japanese input method, so I don't really need the 'extra' US input method, sadly can't remove just the layout and keep the language in the list... So if possible I'd like Windows to default to the Japanese input method, but keep any menus and the likes in English, any suggestions?

Comment: cant you add Japanese input method in language under EN ? its simple but whats the use ?

Comment: @Mahdi with the 'original' Japanese input method you get the "Microsoft IME" thing which seems to be what makes keyboard 'work' with as they should when typing in Japanese, on the other hand just adding Japanese under EN/US doesn't provide the same functionality sadly. Great idea though, it hadn't occurred to me to try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it can be removed by moving down **english (united states)** in language window (`control input.dll`), and then clicking **remove** button:

[image: removing language]

tested on windows 8.1

Comment: finally worked it seems.
Have they made an update recently?

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it, at least in Windows 7 Professional.

On the "keyboards and language" menu go to "Change keyboards" and ask to add a new one in the "Add..." button. Then, go to the language you need (English in your case, because you want English to be the default language) and click on the "+" for "Keyboard", after that select the "Show More..." checkbox and all other languages will be shown. Here you can select your Japanese keyboard layout.

This will accept the input preserving your Japanese keyboard layout, but will keep the defaults (for Office and other software) and menus at English.

Hope it helps!

Comment: 7 is easy. Not a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I fear that is not possible. I had a similar problem with a laptop with a US keyboard layout, which I wanted to use in German language. So i switched the system language to German, but kept using the US English keyboard layout. However, the German keyboard layout kept showing up in the language bar and could not be removed in the language settings. It seems that you have to have at least one keyboard layout per installed language.

What you can do is the following "hack". AFAIK, there is no limitation as to which keyboard can be added to which language. So add one of your desired keyboard layouts (i.e. Japanese) as a new keyboard layout to the **English** language. You should then be able to uninstall the original English keyboard layout. So you basically tell Windows that your Japanese keyboard belongs to the English language. The other layout (Bulgarian) can stay like it is.

As long as you really don't need the English keyboard layout, this solution should be an acceptable workaround. But of course it would be much nicer if Windows 8 would allow separate handling of languages and keyboard layouts, as it used to be up to Windows 7...

Comment: Only problem is Japanese IME doesn't work from non jp. hieroglyph based languages (like English)

Comment: And if you do it the other way round, i.e. add the Bulgarian keyboard layout to the English language and keep Japanese as a separate language?

Comment: it's not available (the one I'm using)

Comment: You mean the keyboard layout? You can always use the [Microsoft keyboard layout creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) to define one and add to a certain language