# How do I change the keyboard layout for the Microsoft IME (Japanese)?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-layout, language, ime, japanese

I have an English Windows install and a Japanese keyboard. I want to type Japanese. I have the Microsoft IME set up and working, but the keyboard layout is wrong. For example, the mode key doesn't work and the symbols on the number keys are wrong.

I already went to

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Parameters

and changed the keyboard to Japanese, which now works fine with English (UK) input. However, the Microsoft IME seems to ignore this setting and default back to a US layout.

How do I change the IME to use my Japanese keyboard properly on Windows 8.1?

Comment: in `intl.cpl`, Languages tab, you need to enable support for east asian languages, then install Japanese keyboard layout. At least, it's like this in XP. With such adequate support in stock utilities, hacking the registry is not a good idea and a recipe for trouble.

Comment: It's not like XP, and the selected keyboard layout does not affect the IME. It seems to pick up the system language, but I don't want to change my OS to Japanese.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/756338/is-there-a-way-to-keep-using-english-as-system-language-on-windows-8-1-but-have linked to in the answer deals with the issue of setting keyboard layouts independently from UI language.

Comment: That doesn't change the IME keyboard layout. My question is specifically about the IME. I don't even have the US keyboard installed or selected for any language, only UK and Japanese. The IME still uses US layout.