# Windows 10 English Display Language with Russian Input Method

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, input-languages, input

I'm struggling to achieve what seems like a quite easy thing.

- I'm running a Windows 10 Laptop installed in English.
- I live in Germany, so `Country or region` (`Settings -> Time & Language -> Region & language`) is set to `Germany`.
- My `Display Language` is set to `English (United States)`.
- As I use a hardware keyboard with US layout, but still need to type some German stuff, I have two keyboard layouts added to the input language - `US` (default) and `German`.

So far, so good. But I recently started learning Russian and now I need to practice typing. I can't add the Russian keyboard layout to the `English (United States)` language - it simply doesn't show up in the list.

To add the keyboard layout to my *hotkey switchable keyboard layout list* is all I want. When I add `Russian` as a language it is obviously being ignored by the keyboard layout switch hotkey, since it's a completely new input method instead of just a keyboard layout, so it keeps switching between `US` and `DE` only.

This is what my language bar looks like with `Russian` added as a language:

[image: Screenshot of Input Methods]

Those are my advanced settings and language bar hotkeys:

[image: Screenshot of and language bar hotkeys]

**Can someone help?** Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want cyclic change `US` =>  `DE` => `RU` using the only hotkey then set up three _languages_ i.e. English(`en-US` keyboard), German(`de-DE`) and Russian(`ru-RU`).

Comment: Wouldn't that change the interaction with different things? Like websites that will then start to preferably show up in Russian when `ru-RU` is currently active? I'd rather have the same language and different keyboard layouts. I mean, I can't be the only one who wants to use English as display language and Russian as input method, right? There needs to be a simple way to set this up.

Answer (score -1):

This question asks the opposite of [another one](https://superuser.com/questions/755640/is-there-a-way-to-use-three-keyboard-languages-having-two-of-them-being-switcha) that i answered, but the [same answer](https://superuser.com/questions/755640/is-there-a-way-to-use-three-keyboard-languages-having-two-of-them-being-switcha#1289261) applies here as well (for the most part). It's possible to add any keyboard layout to any input language via PowerShell. In your case you would need:

```powershell
$OldList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$OldList.Add("en-US")
# German layout (or you can add it via Language screen afterwards)
$OldList[-1].InputMethodTips.Add("0409:00000407")
# Russian layout
$OldList[-1].InputMethodTips.Add("0409:00000419")
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $OldList
```

Keep in mind that spell check is dependent on input language, so you won't be able to use spell check in Russian or German. If you do need spell check in these languages setup three input languages as `JosefZ` stated in a comment.